# ajax response not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a js file under asset/application. here i have troubling an issue which id response.execute(alert("works")) works but response.execute(function(){ alert("not works")}) not works .

```
    this.create = function () {
      var data = jQuery(this).closest('form').serialize();
      POST(jQuery(this).closest('form').attr('action'), data);
      response.execute(alert("hi")); // it works
      response.execute(function(){
        alert("hello") // not works
      });

    }
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: FYI, `response.execute(alert("hi"))` does the alert **before** calling `response.execute()`. So it doesn't wait for the response.

Comment: Are you really calling `response.execute()` twice, or just one of the two ways?

Comment: no matter for twice , it's not work, if i call response.execute once

Comment: but it works after get request like GET(jQuery(this).closest('form').attr('action')); and after that response.execute(function(){alert("works")}) i